# Is there a way to access two firestore projects in a single function by providing the service account credentials?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Firestore projects, `project-a` and `project-b`. I want to access both Firestore databases in a single function. Is there a way to access both databases in a single function?

Example:

- project-a db: `db1 = firestore.Client(project='project-a', credentials=cred1)`
- project-b db : `db2 = firestore.Client(project='project-b', credentials=cred2)`

Comment: I don't recognise the language you are using, but in short, yes, it is possible to access resources from two different Firebase projects. This is a common usage pattern when you have localized resources and databases (e.g. a project for EU, a project for US, etc). N.B. Using multiple projects for the sole purpose of avoiding upgrading to a paid plan is probably against Firebase's ToS.

Comment: As @samthecodingman pointed out, it is possible to link projects. A typical use case is to support your development and production environments. You can read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) for more information.

Comment: Could you expand your question with what you are hoping to achieve by doing this?